# scrollspy hover not showing bootstrap5.2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do a scrollspy like in the bootstrap documentation but I have a little problem with hover. In code you can see i have add hover in cyan color I need for when you down in section it's hover in navbar in name of section, exemple : if you are in contact it's hove where writing contact in navbar

```css
.navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
//   color: cyan;
//   box-shadow: inset 0 -2.5px 0 0 cyan;
// }

// .nav-item a:hover {
//   color: cyan;
//   box-shadow: inset 0 -2.5px 0 0 cyan;
// }
```

```html
 

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-custom" style="padding: 1%;">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="logo.png" alt="Avatar Logo" style="width:40px;" class="rounded-pill">
            </a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-center">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading1">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading2">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading3">Compétences</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading4">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading6">À Propos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading7">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <div data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#navbar-example2" data-bs-root-margin="0px 0px -40%"
        data-bs-smooth-scroll="true" class="scrollspy-example bg-light  rounded-2" tabindex="0">

        <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner" id="scrollspyHeading1">
                <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="10000">
                    <img src="images/114-1144561_copyright-free-images-on-desk-with-laptop-and.jpg"
                        class="d-block w-100" style="filter: brightness(10%);" alt="...">
                    <div
                        class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block d-flex h-50 align-items-center justify-content-center">
                        <h1 class="textanimation2">Portfolio</h1><br>
                        <h1 class="textanimation1" style="font-size: 90px;">Développeur Web Indépendant</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="images/269-2698560_high-resolution-laptop-desktop-wallpaper-hd.jpg" class="d-block w-100"
                        style="filter: brightness(10%);" alt="...">
                    <div
                        class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block d-flex h-50 align-items-center justify-content-center">
                        <h1 class="textanimation3">Création de sites web </h1><br>
                        <h1 class="textanimation4"> vitrine, e-commerce, forum et autres</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="10000">
                    <img src="images/10705380.jpg" class="d-block w-100" style="filter: brightness(10%);" alt="...">
                    <div
                        class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block d-flex h-50 align-items-center justify-content-center">
                        <h1 class="textanimation5">Web design, conception graphiques, </h1> </br>
                        <h1 class="textanimation6">Logos plaquettes publicitaire, cartes de visites,
                            newsletters</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade"
                data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade"
                data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <section class="caseservices" style="padding-top: 4%;" id="scrollspyHeading2">
            <div class="container text-center">
                <h1 class="animationtextprincipal">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span> MES SERVICES
                </h1>
                <h3 style="color: rgb(117, 111, 111);">Des prestations adaptées à vos besoins</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="container text-center">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="row align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-10">
                                <h5 class="text-end">Gestion de projets web</h5>
                                <p class="text-end">Site vitrine, corporate, évènementiel, e-commerce, intranet,
                                    application
                                    mobile.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-laptop-code fa-2xl"></i>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-10">
                                <h5 class="text-end">Intégration Web</h5>
                                <p class="text-end">Des intégrations (X)HTML / CSS respectueuses des standards du Web.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-code fa-2xl"></i>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-10">
                                <h5 class="text-end">Développements spécifiques</h5>
                                <p class="text-end">Des outils adaptés à votre coeur de métier,
                                    applications & solutions personnalisées.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-wrench fa-2xl"></i>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-10">
                                <h5 class="text-end">Référencement naturel</h5>
                                <p class="text-end">Affichage sémantique des informations,
                                    des pages propres pour un référencement optimal.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2">

                                <i class="img-fluid material-icons"><img class="img-fluid w-100"
                                        src="images/5902216.png" alt="" style="width: 100%;"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <img src="images/index.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 d-none d-lg-block" alt="...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="row align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-2">

                                <i class="img-fluid material-icons"><img
                                        src="images/kisspng-icon-design-web-development-responsive-web-design-black-brush-5afd4d493dd9d2.7237427015265498332534.png"
                                        alt="" style="width: 100%;"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-10">
                                <h5 class="text-start">Conception graphique & Webdesign</h5>
                                <p class="text-start">Logos, templates Web, plaquettes publicitaires,
                                    cartes de visite, newsletters...</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-2">

                                <i class="img-fluid material-icons"><img src="images/3938579.png" alt=""
                                        style="width: 100%;"></i>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-10">
                                <h5 class="text-start">Dynamisme des pages</h5>
                                <p class="text-start">Des animations de contenu non intrusives
                                    pour embellir votre projet.</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-2">

                                <i class="img-fluid material-icons"><img src="images/2739572-200.png" alt=""
                                        style="width: 100%;"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-10">
                                <h5 class="text-start">Interface d'administration</h5>
                                <p class="text-start">Outils spécifiques au bon fonctionnement
                                    de votre entreprise.</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-2">

                                <i class="img-fluid material-icons"><img src="images/1027666.png" alt=""
                                        style="width: 100%;"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-10">
                                <h5 class="text-start">Responsive design</h5>
                                <p class="text-start">Compatible tous supports, tablette & application mobile.</p>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="imagesjolie">
            <div class="parallax-header" style="   background: #000;
        background: linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
        ),
        url(1393785.jpg);
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;">
                <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="height: 200px;">
                    <div class="header-content">
                        <h4 class="text-center" style="color: white;">Compatible Mobile, Tablettes & P.C</h4>
                        <h1 class="text-center" style="color: white;">Développement Web Responsive</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container text-center" id="scrollspyHeading3">
            <h1 class="animationtextprincipal" style="padding-top: 4%;">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span> MES COMPÉTENCES
            </h1>
            <h3 style="color: rgb(117, 111, 111);">Des compétences à votre service</h3>
            <div class="container text-center">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-start">
                        <h4>Domaines de compétences</h4>
                        <h6><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check" style="padding-right: 1%;"></i> Gestion de projets web
                        </h6>
                        <p style="font-style: italic;">Site vitrine, corporate, évènementiel, e-commerce, intranet,
                            application
                            mobile.</p>

                        <h6> <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check" style="padding-right: 1%;"></i>Conception graphique &
                            Webdesign </h6>
                        <p style="font-style: italic;">Logos, templates Web, plaquettes publicitaires, cartes de visite,
                            newsletters...</p>

                        <h6><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check" style="padding-right: 1%;"></i>Applications spécifiques
                            et
                            Interface d'administration</h6>
                        <p style="font-style: italic;">PHP - MySQL - AJAX / ASP.NET - C# - SQL</p>

                        <h6><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check" style="padding-right: 1%;"></i>Mise en place /
                            Modification
                            / Gestion de CMS</h6>
                        <p style="font-style: italic;">Wordpress, Joomla, Prestashop, phpBB, IPBoard</p>

                        <h6><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check" style="padding-right: 1%;"></i>Intégration (X)HTML / CSS
                        </h6>
                        <p style="font-style: italic;">Codage à la main respectueux des standards du Web</p>

                        <h6> <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check" style="padding-right: 1%;"></i>Dynamise des pages par
                            JavaScript / AJAX </h6>
                        <p style="font-style: italic;">jQuery, Prototype, Mootools, Scriptaculous</p>

                        <h6><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check" style="padding-right: 1%;"></i>Validation W3C, WAI &
                            référencement naturel SEO</h6>
                        <p style="font-style: italic;"> Accessibilité & ergonomie des pages web </p>

                        <h6><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check" style="padding-right: 1%;"></i> Conception
                            multi-plateformes
                        </h6>
                        <p style="font-style: italic;">Compatible tous supports, tablette & application mobile</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col">
                        <h1>Compétences en développement</h1>
                        <div class="skills-bar">
                            <div class="bar">
                                <div class="info">
                                    <span>HTML/CSS</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress-line html"><span></span></div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="bar">
                                <div class="info">
                                    <span>JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress-line javascript"><span></span></div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="bar">
                                <div class="info">
                                    <span>PHP</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress-line php"><span></span></div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="bar">
                                <div class="info">
                                    <span>laravel</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress-line python"><span></span></div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="bar">
                                <div class="info">
                                    <span>MYSQL</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progress-line mysql"><span></span></div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container text-center" id="scrollspyHeading4">
            <h1 class="animationtextprincipal" style="padding-top: 4%;">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span> MES PROJETS
            </h1>
            <h4 style="color: rgb(117, 111, 111);">Une partie des projets sur lesquels j'ai travaillé</h4>

        </div>

        <div class="imagesjolie">
            <div class="parallax-header" style="   background: #000;
        background: linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
        ),
        url(521120.jpg);
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;">
                <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="height: 200px;">
                    <div class="header-content">

                        <h1 class="text-center" style="color: white;"> PME, associations ou particuliers,
                            je réponds à vos besoins en développement web </h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </br>


        <div class="container text-center" id="scrollspyHeading6">
            <h1 class="animationtextprincipal" style="padding-top: 4%;">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span> À PROPOS
            </h1>
            <h4 style="color: rgb(117, 111, 111);">Je suis développeur web freelance et j'aime ça !</h4>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h4 class="text-start">Un développeur web passionné !</h4>
                    <p class="text-start">Ma passion pour le développement web commence en 2003 et m'a demandé un
                        changement
                        radical de cursus
                        afin de pouvoir pleinement l'exploiter.</br> </br>

                        Dès lors, je mis tout en oeuvre pour percer dans cette voie, tout en prenant du plaisir sur les
                        divers projets développés.</br> </br>

                        En Mai 2009, je décide de devenir développeur web indépendant après plusieurs postes en tant que
                        développeur web « full-stack » réussis, qui me conforteront dans cette idée afin de toucher un
                        plus
                        large panel de domaines d'activités, voir du pays et conquérir le monde !</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col">
                    <img src="images/index.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 d-none d-lg-block" alt="...">
                </div>

                <div class="col">

                    <h4 class="text-start">Expérience en développement</h4>

                    <p class="text-start"> Mon expérience acquise au fil des projets me permet de mieux comprendre les
                        attentes d'un client
                        et de
                        répondre précisement au besoin demandé en fonction du domaine d'activité.</p>

                    <p class="text-start">Du site vitrine au projet plus complexe, je vous propose une expertise et un
                        développement web qui
                        correspond à vos attentes & à vos besoins.</p>

                    <h3 class="text-start">Un tarif adapté à votre projet</h3>

                    <p class="text-start"> Travaillant régulièrement avec des PME, associations ou particuliers, je vous
                        propose des solutions
                        à
                        votre portée & adaptée à votre budget.</p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="imagesjolie">
            <div class="parallax-header" style="   background: #000;
            background: linear-gradient(
              rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
              rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
            ),
            url(1393769.jpg);
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;">
                <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="height: 200px;">
                    <div class="header-content">
                        <h1 class="text-center" style="color: white;"> Un interlocuteur unique pour un site internet
                            réussi
                            !
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container text-center" id="scrollspyHeading7">
            <h1 class="animationtextprincipal" style="padding-top: 4%;">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span> <b>CONTACTEZ-MOI</b>
            </h1>
            

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Xe+8cL9oJa6tN/veChSP7q+mnSPaj5Bcu9mPX5F5xIGE0DVittaqT5lorf0EI7Vk"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ODmDIVzN+pFdexxHEHFBQH3/9/vQ9uori45z4JjnFsRydbmQbmL5t1tQ0culUzyK"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried to make a scrollspy that works like in the bootstrap docs but it doesn't with me. I would like that when I'm in a section there are hover in cyan color that works in the navbar but I can't do it. What's the problem? In this https://testportfolio111.000webhostapp.com/ link i have hosted you can see result

Comment: you want filled the background color when hover a nav link right?

Comment: @Ajithkumar Muthukumaran I need so that when we go down in a section its hover in the navbar, for example if we go down in the contact section in the navbar its hover contact. In the css you can see I tried to make a hover with the color cyan but it doesn't work

Comment: still not getting can you add image any description for your expect

Comment: @xajetin The text turns cyan in the code snippet on hover for me.

Comment: @Ajithkumar Muthukumaran website in this link for exemple when you down in section contact in navbar this is hover contact in navbar

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/Parasin/6zytvs09/41/

Comment: @Ajithkumar Muthukumaran [website](https://www.mathieu-crevoulin.com/) in this link for exemple when you down in section contact in navbar this is hover contact in navbar . Or you can see there :[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/scrollspy/)

Comment: @Ajithkumar Muthukumaran Yes i need like in link what you have send

Comment: Add your code properly! it will helps to solve the issue easier

Comment: @Ajithkumar Muthukumaran there you have all code https://jsfiddle.net/z3hx2Lcr/

Comment: its working right?

Comment: @Ajithkumar Muthukumaran Not working... i need for when go in section do the same with same color like when hover nav-link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246889/discussion-between-ajithkumar-muthukumaran-and-xajetin).

Comment: @Ajithkumar Muthukumaran ok i'm in chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in your CSS and try

```
.navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link.active{
   color: cyan;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2.5px 0 0 cyan;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z3hx2Lcr/